# SQL CountIf a condition is met from another column based on average

Tags: sql, count, looker-studio

I want to get a count of cells in Column A that meet a criteria (average of 10 minutes or more) in Column B using SQL. Apologies as I'm definitely not an SQL expert. Column B has wait times by second and I need to change it to minute, so basically my equation would be Column_B/60, but then also I want to only count the cells in Column A that have an average of 10 minutes or more in Column B. My current formula is below, I know it's off but to give an idea:

```
COUNT(CASE Column_A
WHERE Column_B/60 >= 10)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name WHERE Column_B/60 >= 10;
```

Comment: That didn't work :/ I also should mention I'm in Data Studio and am using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved using the two step process below:

### 1) `HH:MM:SS`

To display `Column_B` in an `HH:MM:SS` format, set the Field Type to:

```
Number > Duration (Sec.)
```

If required, change the aggregation as required, such as to [AVG](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518).

### 2) [CASE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020724) Statement

One way that it can be achieved is by displaying the `Column_B` value in seconds (60 seconds * 10 minutes):

```
COUNT(CASE
    WHEN Column_B >= 600 THEN Column_A
    ELSE NULL END)
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/422c4073-a173-48b6-95b3-447a16aacaf1) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]